# Access values from a custom function inside a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following lines of code for a particular use case. (Using python 2.7)

```
class AutoMap(dict):
    """Implementation of autovivification feature."""
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
        except KeyError:
            value = self[item] = type(self)()
            return value
    def __dir__(self):
        return dict.keys()
    __getattr__ = dict.get
    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__

obj = AutoMap()
AddressMap = AutoMap()

obj["state"] = "Maharastra"
obj["country"] = "India"

AddressMap['address1'] = obj

obj["state"] = "California"
obj["country"] = "USA"

AddressMap['address2'] = obj

print AddressMap # {'address1': {'state' : 'Maharastra', 'country' : 'India'}, 'address2': {'state' : 'California', 'country' : 'USA'}}

def prn_state():
    print "State: " + state


AddressMap['address1']['_prn_state'] = prn_state

AddressMap['address2']['_prn_state'] = prn_state


print AddressMap # {'address1': {'state' : 'Maharastra', 'country' : 'India', '_prn_state': <function prn_state at 0x7fb297dc7320>}, 'address2': {'state' : 'California', 'country' : 'USA', '_prn_state': <function prn_state at 0x7fb297dc7320>}}

print type(AddressMap) # <class 'AutoMap'>

print AddressMap.address2._prn_state()
```

Now, I want whenever I write this line of code it should print "California".
But, it throws an error saying "NameError: global name 'state' is not defined"

Comment: `prn_state` is a function that returns nothing, how are you assigning `AddressMap[address1]['_prn_state'] = prn_state`

Comment: Just provide your code instead of mixing output with it

Comment: Also, `state` inside the function is undefined

Answer (score 2):

`AddressMap` is a `dict`, to get the `state` value of the `address2`:

```
AddressMap = {'address1': {'state' : 'Maharastra', 'country' : 'India'}, 
              'address2': {'state' : 'California', 'country' : 'USA'}}    
print(AddressMap['address2']['state'])
```

**EDIT**:

Wrapped in a function:

```
def states(AddressMap, address):
    return AddressMap[address].get('state', 'Not found')

AddressMap = {'address1': {'state' : 'Maharastra', 'country' : 'India'}, 'address2': {'state' : 'California', 'country' : 'USA'}}
print(states(AddressMap, 'address2'))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
California
```

Comment: Thanks :) But actually it's not a dict, it's a class. I have edited my question and given the entire code.

Answer (score 1):

As the error tells you, `state` is not defined in the global context.
This is working:

```
class AutoMap(dict):
    """Implementation of autovivification feature."""
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
        except KeyError:
            value = self[item] = type(self)()
            return value
    def __dir__(self):
        return dict.keys()
    __getattr__ = dict.get
    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__

    def prn_state(self):
        print "State: " + self.state

obj = AutoMap()
AddressMap = AutoMap()

obj["state"] = "Maharastra"
obj["country"] = "India"

AddressMap['address1'] = obj

obj["state"] = "California"
obj["country"] = "USA"

AddressMap['address2'] = obj

print AddressMap

AddressMap['address1']['_prn_state'] = AddressMap['address1'].prn_state

AddressMap['address2']['_prn_state'] = AddressMap['address2'].prn_state


print AddressMap

print type(AddressMap)

AddressMap.address2._prn_state()
```

Comment: Thanks it helped. :) But the output is shown as "State: California
None". Can you tell why None? Any solution?

Comment: @SarfarazHussain Are you sure that you also changed the last line from `print AddressMap.address2._prn_state()` to `AddressMap.address2._prn_state()` ?

Comment: Yeah now it worked without "print". Thanks. But can we achieve the same without making prn_state() a member function of AutoMap class?

Answer (score 0):

```
class AutoMap(dict):
    """Implementation of perl's autovivification feature."""
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
        except KeyError:
            value = self[item] = type(self)()
            return value
    def __dir__(self):
        return dict.keys()

    __getattr__ = dict.get
    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__


class Sample:
    def __init__(self, d): 
        self.test = d
    def prn_state(self): 
        print self.test.state

obj = AutoMap()
AddressMap = AutoMap()

obj["state"] = "Maharastra"
obj["country"] = "India"
obj["sample"] = Sample(obj)
AddressMap['address1'] = obj

obj["state"] = "California"
obj["country"] = "USA"
obj["sample"] = Sample(obj)
AddressMap['address2'] = obj

AddressMap.address2.sample.prn_state()
```